# How to use Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to build a "Hello World!" MSI custom action dll using Visual Stuio 2012 (if that matters). I've created a new C# project, and browsed to add the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll as a reference in my project.

The problem is that when I build the dll it also copies the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll into the build directory. So, my new custom action dll has a runtime dependency on this Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll. I assume I'm doing something wrong and there's actually a way to get the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll functionality statically linked into my custom action dll...

Comment: See: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out. If you don't use the Votive Visual Studio plugin you have to 'wrap' the finished dll yourself using MakeSfxCA.exe. The documentation is here - https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/DTF/Documents/Guide/Content/buildingcas.htm